# Admob slow down app

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I programmed a game for android in libGDX and I added ads to my app but they slowed it down. CPU usage has increased to ~30%. What should I do? This is my code of [this guide](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads1.php):

```
public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
}

@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, admob banners need some system resources, too. But you could try implementing interstitial ads instead and only show them when player has finished a level etc. That way your game should run still fast.